# Spark Scala match error when comparing values between 2 key value pairs

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

my objective is to read 2 files, filter out stopwords, find common words and pick the word count that is smaller between those two files. Afterwards I should sort the key value pairs in descending order and show only top 15 of the words. So I decided to do it like this:

```
    val conf = new SparkConf()
    conf.setMaster("local")
    conf.setAppName("common words")

    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val stopwords_file = sc.textFile("files/stopwords.txt")
    val file = sc.textFile("files/task1-input1.txt")
    val file2 = sc.textFile("files/task1-input2.txt")

    val stopwords = stopwords_file.collect()

    val counts1 = file.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
      .map(word => word.toLowerCase())
      .filter(!stopwords.contains(_))
      .map(word => (word, 1))
      .reduceByKey(_ + _)

    val counts2 = file2.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
      .map(word => word.toLowerCase())
      .filter(!stopwords.contains(_))
      .map(word => (word, 1))
      .reduceByKey(_ + _)
      .join(counts1)
      .collect()
      .map{ //this line gives the error
        case (k, (v1,v2)) if v1 < v2 => (k,v1) // check if count on file1 is smaller then use file1 count for that word, else use file2 count
      }

    val result = sc.parallelize(counts2).sortBy(_._2, false).take(15)

    result.foreach(println)
```

this gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" scala.MatchError: (http://www.gutenberg.org,(1,1)) (of class scala.Tuple2) at line 30 (the map by case line)
```

I don't really understand the error, any help or suggestion for alternative method would be appreciated. I am new to spark, in hadoop I would map each file into different key value pairs then make them into inputs for reduce function and compare the values in the reduce function but I'm not sure what I should do in spark. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The guarding expression makes your pattern match non-exhaustive. Consider:

```
val f: PartialFunction[(String, (Int, Int)), (String, Int)] = {
  case (k, (v1,v2)) if v1 < v2 => (k,v1) 
}

f.isDefinedAt(("foo", (0, 1)))
// Boolean = true
```

vs.

```
f.isDefinedAt(("foo", (1, 0)))
// Boolean = false
```

You should either drop the guarding expression:

```
val g: PartialFunction[(String, (Int, Int)), (String, Int)] = {
  case (k, (v1,v2)) => if(v1 < v2) (k,v1)  else (k, v2)
}
g.isDefinedAt(("foo", (1, 0)))
// Boolean = true

g.isDefinedAt(("foo", (0, 1)))
// Boolean = true
```

or provide default:

```
val h: PartialFunction[(String, (Int, Int)), (String, Int)] = {
  case (k, (v1,v2)) if v1 < v2 => (k, v1)
  case (k, (_, v2)) => (k, v2)
}

h.isDefinedAt(("foo", (0, 1)))
// Boolean = true

h.isDefinedAt(("foo", (1, 0)))
// Boolean = true
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually, you've made lots of unnecessary jobs like collecting the RDDs. Collecting RDDs collect the whole of the data distributed on the cluster into the master machine.

```
    JavaRDD<String> a = context.textFile("a.txt");
    JavaRDD<String> b = context.textFile("b.txt");
    Set<String> stopwords = null;
    try {
        stopwords = new HashSet(Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("stopwords.txt")));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Set<String> finalStopwords = stopwords;
    JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> aPair = a
            .flatMapToPair(s -> countToOne(s))
            .filter(s -> !finalStopwords.contains(s._1()))
            .reduceByKey((s1, s2) -> s1 + s2);
    JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> bPair = b
            .flatMapToPair(s -> countToOne(s))
            .filter(s -> !finalStopwords.contains(s._1()))
            .reduceByKey((s1, s2) -> s1 + s2);
    List<Tuple2<String, Integer>> collect = aPair.fullOuterJoin(bPair).mapToPair(s -> {
        Integer integer1 = s._2()._2().orNull();
        Integer integer2 = s._2()._1().orNull();
        if (integer1 == null) {
            return new Tuple2<>(s._1(), integer2.intValue());
        } else if (integer2 == null) {
            return new Tuple2<>(s._1(), integer1.intValue());
        }
        if (integer1.intValue() > integer2.intValue()) {
            return new Tuple2<>(s._1(), integer1.intValue());
        }
        return new Tuple2<>(s._1(), integer2.intValue());
    }).collect();
    for (Tuple2<String, Integer> stringIntegerTuple2 : collect) {
        System.out.println(stringIntegerTuple2._1() + "\t" + stringIntegerTuple2._2());
    }
```